# Expression for a still body of water that captures pleasant atmosphere

Tags: expressions

I am searching for a word or expression that describes a still body of water, perhaps a lake. The expression should preferably  also capture the pleasant atmosphere of no waves and minimal sound.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest **placid**:

> having a calm appearance or characteristics
>
> calm and peaceful

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/placid)

There is even a a lake called [Lake Placid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Placid_(New_York)).

There is also a movie called [Lake Placid](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0139414/) (but in this case, the title is ironic).

Answer (score 2):

How about **[tranquil](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tranquil)**?

> free from disturbance or turmoil

Answer (score 2):

I like [**serene**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serene):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1 a** : clear and free of storms or unpleasant change
> // *serene* skies
> **3** : marked by or suggestive of utter calm and unruffled repose or quietude
> // a *serene* smile

Those two senses combine to form a combination of literal and figurative meanings.

Comment: And there is also a Lake Serene: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Serene

Answer (score 0):

In general ecosystem, we use the term ***lentic***  to refer still water body such as a lake or pond.